# Using Markov Chain Monte Carlo to compute the chances that a particular solitaire laid out with 52 cards would come out successfully

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, games, history

Based on some references I got from another question I learned that:

> While convalescing from an illness in 1946, Stan Ulam was playing
>   solitaire. It, then, occurred to him to try to compute the chances
>   that a particular solitaire laid out with 52 cards would come out
>   successfully (Eckhard, 1987).

Interest piqued, I googled on an write up on what Ulam would have done but came up empty handed -- I found countless mentions of this episode but nothing that was step by step.

I found the original paper by Eckhard, [here](http://library.sciencemadness.org/lanl1_a/lib-www/pubs/00326867.pdf), but again it does not address the application to MCMC

So Question:

Does anyone have a pretty introductory write up on how Ulam applied MCMC to solitaire?

Thanks.

Comment: While this is on-topic here, if you don't get a good response here within a couple of days, you may like to flag your post to try migrating to [History of Science and Mathematics SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) to see if it fares better there (it's better not to cross post). If you want to do that, you should first check their help for what's on-topic which should give some idea of what they expect in a question (i.e. you may need to edit to make it on topic there; any such changes would need to be made prior to migration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said by *Paparazzi*, the paper is about [Monte Carlo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174133/what-are-monte-carlo-simulations/174143#174143) method, *not* [Markov Chain Monte Carlo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-would-you-explain-markov-chain-monte-carlo-mcmc-to-a-layperson). MCMC is just a part of a broader family of Monte Carlo methods (i.e., informally, using simulation to solve statistical problems).

This is actually described in the referred paper

> [...] I was convalescing from an illness and playing solitaires. The
>   question was what are the chances that a Canfield solitaire laid out
>   with 52 cards will come out successfully? After spending a lot of time
>   trying to estimate them by pure combinatorial calculations, I wondered
>   whether a more practical method than "abstract thinking" might not be
>   to lay it out say one hundred times and simply observe and count the
>   number of successful plays. [...]

So it's pure Monte Carlo: he simulated a number of plays and then counted the number of events of interest among the all simulated events. It was obtained using a direct simulation.

Actually MCMC was discovered later with Metropolis algorithm being the first MCMC algorithm as described in [*A Short History of Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Subjective Recollections from Incomplete Data*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2902) paper by Robert and Casella (2011).

Answer (score 2):

But there is no evidence he used Markov chain Monte Carlo.  There is no reason to use a probability distribution.  You just shuffle the deck and get a random deck - straight up Monte Carlo.  See Fisher Yates for random shuffle.

Comment: I always thought that Ulam came to Monte Carlo, and not MCMC via the solitaire example.  However I believe that Metropolis as in Metropolis-Hasting algo was at Los Alamos with Ulam .  There is a wonderful article by Diaconnis called something like "THE MCMC revolution" which has a rather nice example of using MCMC to decode encrypted documents.

Comment: I beg to differ.  Perhaps OP has asked a question for which the technical answer is "there is no evidence".  However, while tangential, I think my comments might be of interest to OP.  Feel free to act on your theory and just not reply to this.

Comment: @ Paparazzi Did you read my first comment ? It says explicitly, that Ulam used in your words "straight up" Monte Carlo. So my final comment to you is , meh.  Feel free to continue posting, I'll read, but I am done.

Comment: @aginensky Read my answer.  MCMC is an algorithm not a place.   If you are getting a shuffles with a probability distribution rather than random it is a crooked house.   This is gone  not where.

Comment: Perhaps you can go into more details or back up your answer with some references? Basically I agree, the paper is about how Ulam discovered Monte Carlo, *not* MCMC. MCMC is just a part of multiple different Monte Carlo algorithms and methods.