# What is the trace in a Bayesian Model?

Tags: bayesian, python, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I am studying a python library that uses [Bayesian inference](https://lightweight-mmm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to identify the coefficient of a linear regression.

I have two questions, one very broad and one more vertical on MCMC and [numpyro](https://num.pyro.ai/).

1. What is the sampling trace of a Bayesian Model?
   From my understanding It seems to be the mean of the distribution once I reached the convergence, but I am not sure about that.

In the library specifically [here](https://github.com/google/lightweight_mmm/blob/main/lightweight_mmm/lightweight_mmm.py#L383C3-L383C3) the trace is defined as

```
self.trace = mcmc.get_samples()
```

And this for me is slightly confusing from my first interpretation of "Trace", which makes me think I am wrong.
This because the `mcmc.get_samples()` from [Numpyro Documentation here](https://num.pyro.ai/en/latest/mcmc.html#numpyro.infer.mcmc.MCMC.get_samples)
it seems a way to draw samples (I am not understanding how many, but this is another question off-topic)

If my question format doesn't respect Stack Exchange best practices, please just let me know.

I also read this [very complete answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51467/151809), but I am still struggling understanding the example with Pebbles and Trace

ps I am sorry but I don't have enough reputation to add as new tags `numpyro` and `lightweightmmm`